# UNIX basic getopts trouble

Tags: linux, shell, unix, getopts

I have just recently started using UNIX and having problems trying to implement getopts.

The function below finds a file and then removes it to the recycle bin, tho I'm trying to use getopts with -i that will display a message after it has been moved. The syntax works fine, but when I implement the while loop with the getotps command it no longer works.

Can anybody give me any useful advice, it would be much appreciated

```
function moveToBin(){

while getopts i opt
do
   case $opt in
   i) echo "file removed!" ;;
esac
done

if [[ -e $1 ]]; then
   inode=$(ls -i  $i | cut -d " " -f1)
   name=$1_$inode
   pathOfFile=$(pwd $1)
   restoreEntry=$1_$inode:$pathOfFile/$1

        mv $1 ~/deleted
        mv ~/deleted/$1 ~/deleted/$name
            echo "Before extension code"
               extension=$(find ~ -inum $inode)
 fi
```

Comment: I'd be very leery of using `getopts` in a function.  After the `getopts` loop, you need `shift $(($OPTIND - 1))` to remove the options processed by `getopts`. Then you need to check that there is a `$1` left over (and what should your function do if there's also a `$2` — should you have a `for file in "$@"` loop around the `if`, or should you check for and reject extra arguments? It would be more reassuring if you posted the complete function; your code is missing at least a `}` and who knows what else. It's a good idea to use double quotes around file name arguments to protect against spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
while getopts ...; do
  ...
done
```

getopts will parse options and their possible arguments. It will stop parsing on the first non-option argument (a string that doesn't begin with a hyphen (`-`) that isn't an argument for any option in front of it). It will also stop parsing when it sees the `--` (double-hyphen), which means end of options.